# Can you inspect the field names and types of an uninstantiated JS object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wanting to check an input object to ensure it was of the form that I'm expecting without having to instantiate a new object; is this possible?

I am expecting a `Point` object. A valid `Point` object looks like:

```
{
   name: "Point name",
   x: 32,
   y: 98
}
```

I have a function that takes some input from a source out of my control:

```
function(inputObject) {
   if (!(inputObject instanceof Point)) return false;
   // check fields existence and types
}
```

and I would like to make sure that the three fields are there and that their types are the same as the valid `Point`, i.e., String, Number, Number. This will be checking a large number of points so I would like to avoid creating a new Point to check against every time, how can I achieve this?

Comment: The input object **is** an object. You can use `Object.keys` to check the properties (or `for..in` with a `hasOwnProerty` test) to see if it has what you expect. `instanceof` is not particularly reliable.

Comment: How would you "*check against a new Point every time*"? Maybe show us what you have tried.

Comment: @RobG I could use that to ensure he inputObject fields are a valid subset of `Point`, I seem to need the keys of `Point` to match against rather than the reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful with how strictly you check input values. Javascript is loosely typed, so while you might assign a number to `point.x`, at some point it might be assigned a string.

You can reject the *point* based on a test like:

```
if (typeof point.x != 'number') {
  // bad point
}
```

However, a better strategy might be to ensure the correct Type when the value is assigned.

The *instanceof* operator is useless for ensuring values are of the correct Type (since Type is based entirely on the Type of the value assigned, not on inheritance) and will fail where the contuctor and instance are from different global execution contexts (e.g. across frames). It can also be subverted by modifying the *constructor* property of an object's `[[Prototype]]`.

#### Edit

If you want to validate that an object is a point and you don't want to create a new point to test against, you can create an *isPoint* method that has a closure to an instance and test against that (or use some similar strategy):

```
function Point(name, x, y) {
  this.name = name;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.vectorLength = function() {
  return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
}

Point.isPoint = (function() {
  var point = new Point('name', 0, 0);
  return function(obj) {
    for (var prop in point) {
      if (!(prop in obj) && typeof point[prop] != typeof obj[prop]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
}());

var a = new Point('a',0,0);

alert(Point.isPoint(a)); // true

alert(Point.isPoint({name:'b', x:0, y:0})); // false, no inherited vectorLength method
```

However none of this ensures that property values have a particular Type, for that a setter method is likley more robust.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof inputObject.name == "string" & typeof inputObject.x == "number" & typeof inputObject.y == "number")
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more generic/dynamic, i.e., compare an input object to the constructor of the object type I was expecting.

Comment: `if (someBoolean) { return true; } else { return false; }` is an antipattern. `return someBoolean;` does the exact same thing.

Comment: to be honest I put them in as placeholders as there is no telling whether the function only returns a boolean value or will go on to do some processing